# ImageMagick's display GPU "memory leak"?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, imagemagick

I'm testing CUDA app and I have run into strange memory issue:

My program performs some image operations and displays it using ImageMagick's display program.
The problem is that every time I run that IM's display I get more GPU memory usage, so less memory for GPU computation.

I'm using IM's display, because I couldn't find anything that displays image from the pipe input. Any suggestions?

Anyway why IM's display takes so much GPU memory and why is it not freed?

Comment: What is the size of displayed images? When do you close the `display` program?

Comment: Image is quite big: its' 8bit 3872x2592. But it's displayed and processed fine. I use `popen` to write to the `display` process. Then I usually press ESC to close display program, and host program is then also closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's old, but we have figured out that using pipes (`popen()`) makes sophisticated copy of the program in memory, what also causes copying the end program directives, or whatever called... So when I close program opened with `popen` I also finish all CUDA related context that are usually freed in "background", when program ends. So cleaning CUDA memory after I close `popen` application won't work, and I thing here was my memory leak and general major program error.

I hope someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, you're attempting to display a series of files in sequence using a shell not unlike Bash after performing a set of GPU-intensive operations. You're curious why more GPU memory is being consumed with every subsequent invocation of ImageMagick [`display`](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/display.html), which appears to be closing out successfully after the conclusion of each operation.

We may further theorize that you're using ImageMagick's [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) support for at least some of your processing. While we don't have enough information to determine what your GPU's texture buffers look like at the completion of each rendering via `display`, I speculate your GPU isn't freeing textures expediently, causing memory to slowly creep up.

Instead of continuing to build conjecture around this hypothesis, I will instead recommend a tool to debug your issue: [**gDEBugger**](http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php). This should allow you to interrogate your video card to determine exactly why things are slowing down.

Best of luck with your application.